# How can I write a function whose prototype should be 'void convertstring(char *)' to convert lower case to upper case in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

This is what I've written

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convertstring(char *str[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (*str[i] >= 'a' && *str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            *str[i] = *str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    gets(str);
    convertstring(&str);
    printf("Uppercase string : %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no output at all in this case. I want to return the the full text in upper case characters while using the void function. This could be done using other types of functions but this is the challenge that the function must be of type void convertstring(char *)

Comment: You should use `toupper` instead of `- 32`.

Comment: Where in the world did you learn to use `gets()`? That function should **never** be used; it's the only one so bad it was actually removed from the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

First of all, you're using `gets`, which was deprecated in C99 and removed in C11. Instead, use `fgets`:

```
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), 100);
```

Second, you're passing a pointer to an array to the function. You shouldn't do that.

Along with the last point, you're operating on a `char *[]` in your function. Instead, use a `char *`, like so:

```
void convertstring(char *str)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
}
```

You really ought to get a good book on C or learn about pointers.